# How to create button go to next questions in Quiz Software

Tags: java, javascript

I'm creating a Quiz Software with 40+ questions. Problem is when I click the "Next" Button, I would like to make the current question and answer go and a new set come there in the same frame while also keeping the marks user got for previous question. I can make 40+ Jframes Forms but that would too complicated.

UPDATE: Simply when I click "Next" Button, the question in question box and answers of the radio buttons will change. But this has to be done over and over again, by same button. There's also this previous button that will remove the current question and go back to the last one.

To make things more complicated, each time the there will be different IF selections as the the radio button congaing correct answer also changes.

As I said I can design JFrame forms for each but I'm having a hard taking the marks of each question for one frame (called "Final Result") And there's also this timer that countdown from one hour. I don't think I can do either of these by creating 40+JFrame forms.

Comment: you say java / javascript.. they are both mutually exclusive.  Which one are you doing?  Java? or JavaScript.  Considering you are using JFrame's, my best guess would be Java.. Please disambiguate these

Comment: Explain your case clearly. If u can't get output, better u post ur code. We will solve that

Comment: Yeah it's Java. And I'm creating via netbeans

Comment: @Prasanna That's the prob. I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create just one Frame and on the 'Next' Button Handler, Change Label Text, Check Box Text (Assuming Multiple choice questions)

Comment: I know but what about the answers? Each will have different answers thus different variable each time I click "Next". Thats the part I fail to do

Comment: Collect Answers into a Collection, if possible